# Conditionally required value in Pydantic v2 model

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm working with an API that accepts a query parameter, which selects the values the API will return. Therefore, when parsing the API response, all attributes of the Pydantic model used for validation must be optional:

```py
class InvoiceItem(BaseModel):
    """
    Pydantic model representing an Invoice
    """

    id: PositiveInt | None = None
    org: AnyHttpUrl | None = None
    relatedInvoice: AnyHttpUrl | None = None
    quantity: PositiveInt | None = None
```

However, when creating an object using the API, some of the attributes are required. How can I make attributes to be required in certain conditions (in Pydantic v1 it was possible to use metaclasses for this)?

Examples could be to somehow parameterise the model (as it wouldn't know without external input how its being used) or to create another model `InvoiceItemCreate` inheriting from `InvoiceItem` and make the attributes required without re-defining them.

Comment: Under what conditions would the attributes be required? Is this e.g. if two other attributes are None?

Comment: Reason I'm asking is there could be a couple of different solutions to this - model_validators and disciminated unions spring to mind

Comment: Having re-read the question, I think I see what you're getting at, e.g. all items being none is invalid

Comment: @Mark thanks for your comments! I initially was thinking about two different models, basically create another one called `InvoiceItemCreate(InvoiceItem)` inheriting from the one I have and use a `model_validator` to make sure the required attributes are there. Maybe it's also possible to parameterise the model. It depends on where the model is used, e.g. reading from the API or passing data to the API. Guess the separate class is the easiest option

Comment: No worries - yeah so you can create a mixin that contains a model validator if you want to, then use this in whichever models require it - I'll put up my solution below

Comment: The challenge is that this would modify the original object at all times, so even when used in the context of fetching info, the validator would apply. What I need is some way to tell the model that its "used in data fetching context", which means all fields are optional or that its "used in data writing context", which means certain fields are required. I believe the Mixin approach will still work, I'll try something and post an update. Thanks!

Comment: Ah interestingly enough this is a problem I've also faced in pydantic v1, where trying to make models for different CRUD routes, that are essentially based on the same model. I would suggest trying to make separate models for each use case, but have the models be based on the same base class of attributes, just using different model_validators via mixins

Comment: This sounds like a good opportunity to use [discriminated union](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by Marks answer I ended up using something like this:

Mixin generator pattern:

```py
from typing import Self
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator


def required_mixin(required_attributes: list[str | list[str]]):


    class SomeRequired(BaseModel):

        @model_validator(mode="after")
        def required_fields(self) -> Self:
            for v in required_attributes:
                if isinstance(v, str):
                    if getattr(self, v) is None:
                        raise ValueError(f"{v} attribute is required but is None")
                else:
                    if not any(getattr(self, attr) is not None for attr in v):
                        raise ValueError(f"One of {v} is required.")

            return self

    return SomeRequired
```

Actual class

```py
class InvoiceItem(BaseModel):
    """
    Pydantic model representing an Invoice
    """

    id: PositiveInt | None = None
    quantity: PositiveInt | None = None
    unitPrice: float | None = None
    totalPrice: float | None = None
    title: str | None = None
    description: str | None = None


class InvoiceItemCreate(
    InvoiceItem,
    required_mixin(["title", "quantity", ["unitPrice", "totalPrice"]]),
):
    """
    Pydantic model representing an Invoice
    """
```

This allows me to re-use the definitions of the actual class and create an additional model based on the old one. The model validator allows to define certain attributes that are required when using the `InvoiceItemCreate` model, and even allows little more complex scenarios like "either `unitPrice` or `totalPrice` is required.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, there I've asserted that at least one attribute is required, but you could also impose other conditions on the attributes through the model validator:

```py
from typing import Self
from pydantic import HttpUrl, BaseModel, PositiveInt, model_validator


class AllRequired(BaseModel):
    @model_validator(mode='after')
    def not_all_none(self) -> Self:
        if all(v is None for _, v in self):
            raise ValueError('All values were none')
        return self

class InvoiceItem(AllRequired):
    """
    Pydantic model representing an Invoice
    """

    id: PositiveInt | None = None
    org: HttpUrl | None = None
    relatedInvoice: HttpUrl | None = None
    quantity: PositiveInt | None = None

    
InvoiceItem(id=None, org=None, relatedInvoice=None, quantity=None) # Invalid item
```